# Area51 multiple OpenID login goof

Tags: support, area-51, user-accounts, openid, merge-accounts

I just logged in to my Area 51 account from a second computer using my alternate OpenID information. From there I clicked through some screens about associating my account with others on the Trilogy websites without really reading them (yeah, yeah, I know, user error, RTFM, OMGWTFBBQ and all that.)

Now I have two unique user accounts on Area 51, both of which seem to be associated with my other Trilogy accounts. Can they be merged together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, just send mail to the **contact us** link at the bottom (area51@stackoverflow.com).